# Is it possible to redirect different pages by checking radio button value in form submit?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>User Login</h3>
    @Model.Msg
    <form method="post" asp-page="Login">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Email Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" asp-for="@Model.Password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Select whether you are a doctor or patient:
                    <p></p>
                    <input type="radio" id="doc" name="gender" value="Doctor">
                    <label for="doc">Doctor</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="pat" name="gender" value="Patient">
                    <label for="pat">Patient</label><br />
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" name="sub"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using TeleHealthB.Models;


namespace TeleHealthB.Pages
{
    public class LogInModel : PageModel
    {
       
        [BindProperty]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Msg { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        
        public IActionResult OnPost(string sub )
        {
            using (var context = new HealthProjectContext())
            {
                try

                {
                    var query = from st in context.Patients
                                where st.Email == Username
                                select st.Password;

                    string check2 = query.FirstOrDefault();
                     

                   
                    if (Password.Equals(check2.Trim()))
                    {
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Username", Username);
                        return RedirectToPage("Welcome");
                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Msg = "Invalid";
                        return Page();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Msg = "Invalid";
                    return Page();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is from one of the razorpages of a website I'm working on. The code is currently setup to where the users are sent to one general login page. I'd like to allow users to click a radio button to make a distinction between patient or doctor and send them to the corresponding webpage. I'm fairly new to asp.net so I'm not 100% it is possible to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `Gender` property to Model so that you can redirect different page by checking that value in `OnPost`, something like that:

```
namespace TeleHealthB.Pages
{
    public class LogInModel : PageModel
    {
       
        [BindProperty]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        
        [BindProperty]
        public string Gender { get; set; } //--> This is a new property
        
        public string[] Genders = new[] { "Doctor", "Patient" };}

        public string Msg { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        
        public IActionResult OnPost(string sub )
        {
            using (var context = new HealthProjectContext())
            {
                try

                {
                    var query = from st in context.Patients
                                where st.Email == Username
                                select st.Password;

                    string check2 = query.FirstOrDefault();
                     

                   
                    if (Password.Equals(check2.Trim()))
                    {
                        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Username", Username);
                        
                        //You can redirect pages by checking Gender values
                        if(Gender  == "Doctor")
                        {
                           return RedirectToPage("Welcome_Doctor");
                        }
                        else if(Gender == "Patient")
                        {
                           return RedirectToPage("Welcome_Patient");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Msg = "Invalid Gender";
                            return Page();
                        }
                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Msg = "Invalid";
                        return Page();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Msg = "Invalid";
                    return Page();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also radio buttons should be :

```
@foreach (var gender in Model.Genders)
{
    <input type="radio" asp-for="Gender" value="@gender" />@gender<br />
}
```